# Fire event at when div reaches certain PX

Tags: javascript, html

Hi If could please take a look at my code and tell me what the next step I am looking for to get this result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function doMove1() {
      foo1.style.left = parseInt(foo1.style.left)+1+'px';
      setTimeout(doMove1,20); // call doMove in 20msec
    }
    function start1() {
      foo1 = document.getElementById('fooObject'); // get the "foo" object
      foo1.style.left = '0px'; // set its initial position to 0px
      doMove1(); // start animating
    }
window.onload = start1;
</script>
<body>
        <div id="fooObject"> 
    <img src="images/pac.gif" width="38" height="38"></div> 
</body>
```

Basically what happens is that a image moves across the screen.What i am trying to accomplish is that when the image gets to a certain px (Lets say 900px) I want an event to fire. Any tips on accomplishing this task I am a beginner Ive been working on this all day before i thought to seek help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check for this in `doMove1`:

```
function doMove1() {
  var left = parseInt(foo1.style.left, 10) + 1;
  if (left >= 900) {
    trigger_my_event();
  } else {
    foo1.style.left = left + 'px';
    setTimeout(doMove1,20); // call doMove in 20msec
  }
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thankyou that is what exactly I wanted. I Made something similiar to this but I made variable like --- var ypos = foo1.style.left. I really appreciate your help.